# Preselecting values in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have an app I'm working on. This app uses ASP.NET MVC 4. One of my screens has a drop down list and a check box. This screen is a basic signup form. The model for the form currently looks like the following:

```
public class SignUpModel
{
  public int SelectedBirthMonth { get; set; }
  public bool Agree { get; set; }
  public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

The relevant view code looks like the following:

```
@model MyApp.Models.SignUpModel
...
<input id="Username" name="Username" value="@Model.Username"  />
<select id="SelectedBirthMonth" name="SelectedBirthMonth">
  <option value="1">January</option>
  <option value="2">February</option>
  <option value="3">March</option>
  ...
  <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
<input id="Agree" name="Agree" type="checkbox" />
```

For the most part, this works. Except, when a user posts the form, I do some validation. If the validation fails, I show the user the view again. My intent was to have they're previously entered values entered. My current approach is working with the Username text box. However, I don't know how to handle drop down lists such that they're previously selected value is selected, and how to check the checkbox if they previously checked it.

How does one address these types of scenarios in ASP.NET MVC 4?

Thank you!

Comment: pass the model back to the view after validation fails and use the mvc html helpers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try posting the form via ajax and return a boolean to the callback, if true then redirect to the next page, if false, you just remain where you are.